# Prove separation method of GS1 structured datamatrix

Tags: barcode, gs1-datamatrix

I work with barcodes professionally so usually dive fairly deep into the specs.

But I have one thing that I have not been able to do so far. A datamatrix GS1 structured code may be separated by FNC1 or GS. The most common in professional label software is FNC1.

Two versions of the same code is below, encoding GS1 structure `(01)03041094787443(21)5Qbag!(93)Zjqw`

My question is to **prove** which separator is used, preferably using code (python or other, that's not very important).

I have tried using the free version of [BCTester](https://bctester.de), but as specification goes, I get `"GS" (0x1d)` returned for both versions.  Every mobile scanner same result, or no technical information at all. Data scans the same for both.

[image: FNC1 formatted]  FNC formatted

[image: GS formatted] GS formatted (created by zintQt)

Comment: Take a look at the [zxing online decoder](https://zxing.org/w/decode.jspx) (no affiliation).  It shows the raw decoded bytes.  With datamatrix, FNC1 is the 0xe8 code word.  For example, your second barcode shows FNC1 as the first delimiter, and GS1 (0x1e) as the second.

Comment: Thank you for the link. [guide to decode raw bytes](https://barcode-coder.com/en/datamatrix-specification-104.html) for further work.